# AnalogX Proxy on Windows: Would it be possible to make it secured?

Tags: http, proxy, internet, http-proxy

I am using AnalogX Proxy Server to share my internet connection, my question is, would it be possible or does this software supports authentication? I mean, connecting to the proxy will require login username/password authentication? So that even if  someone got the proxy's ip and port, especially those tech savvy users, still won't be able to connect.

OR, maybe you can recommend another 'free' proxy server software that is secure and trusted that is capable of what I am seeking?

Comment: If you have the software installed look what you can configure. Based on the online documentation their is no authentication. And, recommending any products is off-topic here.